# Не переведены несколько текстов в Привилегиях

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На [странице описаний привилегий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) несколько мест не переведны.

1. Подзаголовок:

> Privileges control what you can do on Stack Overflow на русском. Gain more privileges by increasing your reputation (points you receive from your fellow users for posting helpful questions and answers).

2. Привилегия за 4.000

> trusted user
>   Expanded editing, deletion and undeletion privileges

3. Привиления за 15

> flag posts
>   Bring content to the attention of the community via flags

4. Привилегия за 10

> create wiki posts
>   Create answers that can be easily edited by most users

Comment: Насколько я помню, всё это уже было переведено. Пинганул координатора сообщества в чате.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Переводу могу «слететь», например, если была исправлена опечатка в англоязычном варианте.  Если такое происходит, то предыдущий перевод можно найти в разделе «Предложения».

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: в этом случае вряд ли были исправления, там просто негде опечататься: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1506/181472

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: а в целом спасибо за объяснение, понял причину.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Недопереведено описание привилегий](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b9) Предлагаю перенести ответ туда и ознакомиться с другими варианами.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky было бы круто, если бы английский вариант тоже был бы полноценной локализацией, т.е. в базе хранились бы только идентификаторы строк (например, краткая формулировка и контекст). В таком случае чужие переводы бы не слетали из-за небольшой смены английского текста. Но, вероятно, в нынешних масштабах за это вряд ли возьмутся, а может, и смысла в этом не так уж и много.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev отличная идея.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю следующие варианты:

1. Подзаголовок

> Привилегии определяют ваши возможности на Stack Overflow на русском. Для получения дополнительных привилегий поднимайте свою репутацию (очки, получаемые от других участников сообщества за публикацию хороших и полезных вопросов и ответов)

2. Trusted user

> Поверенный пользователь
>   Дополнительные возможности редактирования, удаления и восстановления привилегий

3. flag posts

> маркировать сообщения
>   обратить внимание модератора на содержание поста

4. create wiki posts

> создавать общие посты
>   давать ответы, которые могут быть отредактированы другими пользователями

Comment: Кстати, довольно хороший перевод. Его стоит опубликовать в том вопросе.